# Why the space suit looks white in Millers planet in the movie Interstellar?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-redshift, interstellar-travel

1. The accretion disk of Gargantua (the black hole in the movie) is
   red (or orange) in color (probably because of red shift due to intense gravity?). And the Millers planet is revolving around this black hole. So the planet is powered by red light (unlike white sunlight in the case of our earth).

   This being the case, the space suit must appear red in color as red is the only color available over there. But it looks white in the movie. Is it a loophole in the movie or I am making some mistakes?

[Link to photo of suit on Miller's planet](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAZ6Bjk8f2L0ZLPGkXNvRt0VC68_acyhhD61iYAZ172LW2qSzPyU2nPeKb)

[Link to photo of Gargantua.](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRgXAo-zl7SyizeS0vTw1Y45_IkLMCnYhi52Bp499jOa45d3Ce6afGyqkPwiQ)

2. And the voice transmitters fitted to the space suit must also not
   work, right? As the electrical signals are transmitted, they will also undergo some shift in wavelength and so a corrupted information will be received by the receiver which will be decoded wrongly. Am I correct?

I understand it is a movie. But just want to know the correct stuff. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the suit?

Comment: @Yashas Samagam A pic has been added

Comment: To me the picture of the suit looks a little bit red-shifted, similar to the light during a sunset. The situations are comparable, since in both situations the spectrum is shifted to lower frequencies, in one case due to the gravitational redshift, in the other case due to wavelength dependent refraction indices, but the result is similar.
I'm not sure if the effect is really underestimated in the movie.
What is important to mention is that the observed redshift of the accretion disk is decreasing the nearer you get to Gargantua. So in the pictures from further away the redshift is stronger.

Comment: Voted to close because this is about movie production, not physics.

Comment: @WillO My thought is that http://movies.stackexchange.com/ people won't be answering a movie related question that has too much of physics. If it is related to basic physics or Newtonian concepts, then that forum would do. And that is why I posted it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about a film not physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Digital cameras, and human eyes, compensate for varying "colors" of light and generally render the brightest as "white". This is akin to looking through blue filter sunglasses and still perceiving things as "white". Without measurements and more hard data, I see no reason as to why a similar compensation couldn't have been made to render the suite apparently white.
2. We do not know what specific technology the communicators use, nor what their capabilities are regarding restoring corrupted data.
3. As you acknowledge, it's a movie. The liberties taken in movie production often make it laughable to try and apply real scientific understandings. Case in point? The arm thrusters have no visible storage tanks.